# How can I return HTML loop from JSON in controller to blade

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

I have code in my controller to get city of a store and in the same time I want to get back this store categories. It's all working fine but results of categories come like this:

```
["Taco Bar", "Yogurt Bar", "Hot Breakfast", "Utensils", "Beverages", "Desserts", "Salads", "Ala Carte", "Party Essentials"]
```

How can I view these categories in the HTML table?

```
public function getCity($id)
{
  $store_city = Storeinfo::where('store_id', $id) -> pluck('store_city');
  $categories = Category::where('store_id', $id) -> pluck('Category_name');
  return Response::json(array(
    'store_city' => $store_city,
    'categories' => $categories,
  ));
}
```

```js
success: function(data) {
  $('#store_city').val(data.store_city);
  console.log(data.categories);
}
```

Comment: `data.categories.forEach(function(category) { /* your logic here... */ });` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: or a jQuery `$.each(data.categories, function(key, value) { /* your logic here... */ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

JS:

```
success:function(data){

  $('#store_city').val(data.store_city);

   var tableCOntent = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Categories</th></tr>";

   data.categories.forEach(function(item){

      tableCOntent += "<tr><td>" + item + "</td></tr>";
   });

   tableCOntent += "</table>";

   $('.table-data').html(tableCOntent);

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sort of dynamic component. First of all create a directory inside views folder and name it "dynamicComponents"(I usually name it like that), inside this folder create a blade file name it whatever you want(ex. categoriesTable.blade.php). This file should look like:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<style>
    //All the style you need for this component 
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //All the javascript you need for this component 
    });
</script>
```

And the main file(the file where you want to show the table) should look like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Categories</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="dynamicCompnentWrapper">
        @include('dynamicComponents.categoriesTable')
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also you have to create a javascript function that look like:

```
function reload(url, method, wraperClass,id){
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/' + method + '/' + id,
        success: function (result) {
            $('.' + wraperClass).html(result.html);
        }
    });
}
```

In controller class you have to add a method name it what ever you want(usually I name it
reload) and it look like:

```
public function reloadCategoriesTable($id)
    {
        if (request()->ajax()) {
            $categories= Category::where('store_id', $id)->get();
            $html = view('dynamicComponents.categoriesTable', compact('view', 'categories', 'folder'))->render();
            return response()->json(compact('html'));
        }
        return view('errors.404');
    }
```

You also need to create a route for the added controller function.

So the first time the user loads the page the table will be shown using data from getCity() or even better from index method and when ever you make changes you can call javascript function (

```
reload('your base url ex. www.blabla.com', ' function that you created in controller in this case reloadCategoriesTable', 'wrapper class from table body dynamicCompnentWrapper',id_of_category)
```

), this function calls the method in controller and reloads("re-draws"  the table every time you call reload() function from javascript).